# pandas Series sort_index with key

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort a Series using `sort_index(key = lambda idx: foo(idx))`, which should take the first item of the list and put it at the end. My sorting function `foo` looks like this:

```
def foo(idx):
    print("pre",idx)
    if idx.name == "pca_n":
        ret = pd.Index(list(idx[1:]) + list(idx[:1]),name=idx.name)
    else:
        ret = idx.copy()
    print("post",ret)
    return ret
```

I call it like this:

```
print("index before sort",byHyp.index)
byHyp = byHyp.sort_index(key = lambda x: foo(x))
print("index after sort",byHyp.index)
```

This results in the following output:

```
index before sort Int64Index([-1, 2, 5, 10, 20], dtype='int64', name='pca_n')
pre Int64Index([-1, 2, 5, 10, 20], dtype='int64', name='pca_n')
post Int64Index([2, 5, 10, 20, -1], dtype='int64', name='pca_n')
index after sort Int64Index([20, -1, 2, 5, 10], dtype='int64', name='pca_n')
```

In other words, the output of `foo` gives a list of indices, but they are not retained in the Series. (I am expecting `[2,5,10,20,-1]`, as is the output of foo). Perhaps I am misunderstanding how to use the `key` argument of `sort_index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) explain:

> key: callable, optional
>
> If not None, apply the key function to the index values **before sorting**.

In other words, `foo` gets called and returns an index `[2,5,10,20,-1]`. After that, your df index gets sorted according to the output of `foo`:

- the output of foo in your example is already nearly sorted, we just have to make the final element `-1` the first element
- this means your df's index will go from `[-1, 2, 5, 10, 20]` to `[20, -1, 2, 5, 10]`, which is exactly what your output shows.

I think what you are trying to do is not sort the index, but rather reorder it using `foo` like this:

```python
print("index before-ordering",byHyp.index)
byHyp = byHyp.loc[foo(byHyp.index), :]
print("index after re-ordering",byHyp.index)
```

... or, as pointed out by OP in a comment, if the input is a Series then:

```python
byHyp = byHyp[foo(byHyp.index)]
```

Output:

```
index before-ordering Int64Index([-1, 2, 5, 10, 20], dtype='int64', name='pca_n')
pre Int64Index([-1, 2, 5, 10, 20], dtype='int64', name='pca_n')
post Int64Index([2, 5, 10, 20, -1], dtype='int64', name='pca_n')
index after re-ordering Int64Index([2, 5, 10, 20, -1], dtype='int64', name='pca_n')
```

Comment: Your solution is much nicer, thank you. However, I still don't understand why the df's index changes like this. "We just have to make the final element -1 the first element" - what does that mean?

Comment: Also, the proper syntax for my use case is byHyp.loc[foo(byHyp.index)] , this is a Series not a DataFrame (edit suggestion)

Comment: Edited to add the syntax where the input is a Series, as in your case. Regarding your query as to "why the df's index changes like this", I guess what I'm trying to say is this: you know exactly how you want to modify the index, so there is no need to sort, but rather simply to re-order the index in the order you know you want, and this is what my answer does.

Answer (score 1):

If you just return the list of the order that you want as a regular list then do `df.loc[returned list]` it will order it they way you want it ordered. Notice below the index goes from 1912 to 1916, but you can reset it to be any order you with with `df.loc[your_new_order]`.
[image]